# & JavaScript includes

Tags: javascript, xss, owasp

OWASP's XSS Filter Evasion Cheat Sheet mentions "& JavaScript includes":

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet#.26_JavaScript_includes

The example it provides is as follows:

```
<BR SIZE="&{alert('XSS')}">
```

I tried it on jsfiddle with Chrome and Firefox and I'm not getting a JS popup. So on what browsers / versions is this supposed to work on?

The URL:

http://jsfiddle.net/rL1z32xb/

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/a/64926/56707

Comment: There's a Q&A about this on another SE site -- [XSS Technique - & JavaScript Include](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/64925/xss-technique-javascript-include)

Answer (score 9):

You'll need to break out your copy of Netscape 4 to reproduce it.

Newer versions of Netscape (and every other browser) do not allow that use of the `&` operator.